# React: Validate that no extra props has been passed

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `propTypes` with React because I like how it warn me when I pass something dumb. But sometimes I misspell my prop or I forget to put it in my `propTypes` and it never get validated.

**Is there a (standard) way to make React also validate that no extra props have been passed ?**

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this. As of now, I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's a standard way, but you can certainly do a quick and dirty check using `Object.keys`.

```
var propsCount = Object.keys(this.props).length,
    propTypesCount = Object.keys(this.propTypes).length;

if(propsCount === propTypesCount) {
  // correct number of props have been passed
}
```

The only edge case you will have to watch for is `props.children`, as this arrives as an implicit property if you nest components/HTML inside your component.

If you want a more fine grained approach, then you'll have to pick out the keys and iterate them yourself, checking.

```
var passedPropNames = new Set(Object.keys(this.props)),
    expectedPropNames = new Set(Object.keys(this.propTypes));

passedPropNames.forEach(function(propName) {
  if(!expectedPropNames.has(propName)) {
    console.warn('Not expecting a property called', propName);
  }
});

expectedPropNames.forEach(function(propName) {
  if(!passPropNames.has(propName)) {
    console.warn('Expected a property called', propName);
  }
});
```

Comment: Definitely, a mixin which returns a descriptor that identifies missing and surplus props would be super-reusable.

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you ask.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    let matchPropTypes = Object.keys(this.constructor.propTypes).every((a, index) => a === Object.keys(this.props)[index])
    if (!matchPropTypes) {console.log('propTypes do not match props', Object.keys(this.constructor.propTypes), Object.keys(this.props))}
  }
```

Comment: Your answer assumes props and proptypes are in the same order.  This is only safe to do if eslint is set to sort both the same way. `"react/sort-prop-types": 1, "react/jsx-sort-props": 1,`